# How to find annotation properties of an Owl ontology using Java Jena?

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology, apache-jena

I am developing a project on ontology using Java Jena and that needs annotation properties like 'sameAs', level, comment etc.

Comment: If you really mean `owl:sameAs`, since when is it an annotation property?

Comment: According to your question, I can always only say please read documentation and Javadoc: `OntModel::listAnnotationProperties` , see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listAnnotationProperties--